# Is it possible to locate/find an item using console in Morrowind?

Tags: cheats, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

The problem is that I had found an item early in the game which turned out to be a quest item later.

It didn't look very useful so I sold it right away.

And now I am stuck since I don't know where I sold it or dropped it.

Because this is a unique item, is it possible to find its location using console?

I am aware of the fact that in worst scenario I can just spawn a copy of the item. Nevertheless, I'd love to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Getpos[x, y, or z]` command to get the coordinates of an object. You would need to append the id of the object you're looking for  to that command (`ItemID->`). Using the Sunder item as an example your command would look like this `sunder->Getpos, x`. You can use `player->Getpos[x,y,z]` to get the coordinates of yourself in order to determine you are heading in the correct direction.

You can use `PlaceAtPC, [ItemID], [Count], [Distance], [Direction]` command to place an object near you. Note taht it's recommended to use 1 as the Distance and Direction.

You can also add a copy of the item into your inventory by using `AddItem [ItemID] [count]`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Assuming I am looking for the *Sunder* - should the command look like this: `sunder->Getpos[x]`?

Comment: @moonnoon in this case yes, you would get the ID from the wiki: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sunder underneath the picture it will tell you the `ID` and then you'd use that.

Comment: @moonnoon also it'd be `getpos, x`

Comment: um, well, the funny thing is that it tells `"sunder" not found` :D

Comment: @moonnoon well it looks like you didn't drop it then or if you did it has despawned. The other option is that if you sold it, I doubt this command will locate it inside a merchant's inventory, and even if it could it's probable that it no longer exists in the shop that you sold it at. Just use one of the other commands I've given to spawn a new one.

Comment: You make it sound like your just providing the item name, not the item ID

Comment: @Timelord64 what do you mean? where have I written to use the name? I've said to use the ID

Comment: One last thing - could you please tell me how to interpret the value of the output of the getpos command?

Comment: Ahh I get it. "sunder" is the ID.

Comment: @moonnoon it's the x y or z coordinate, what do you need help with, could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: How can I find the item when I've checked its coordinates?

Comment: @moonnoon Just go to those coordinates, you can use the same command on the player `player->getPos, x` to get your coordinates to make sure you're heading in the right direction.